# Difference between two dates C language

Tags: c, windows, macos, compatibility

!! Edited

The following is a different try, I have `rawtime` as result, so just seconds and I need to convert in number of days, probably doing `rawtime / 86400`.  But even with this code windows gives always `0` as result, and xcode works properly.

```c
typedef struct {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    char fiscalCode[17];
    STATESICK stateSick;
    struct tm start;
    struct tm end;
} SICKREGION;

    { "PlutoPluto", "Leonardi", "GRSBDT06B48F839T", stayHome, { 0, 0, 0, 28, 2, 2020 }, { 0, 0, 0, 29, 2, 2020 }},

void timeDiff() {
    double rawtime = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
                rawtime = difftime(mktime(&region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k].end),
                                   mktime(&region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k].start));
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%g\n", rawtime);
}
```

I'm working on a project for my C class with my colleagues.
We have a problem, we need to get the difference between dates taken from structs.
The function I made **works but just on my mac, on Windows doesn't work.**, we have `0` as result, anytime. does anyone knows why? 
Thanks, Sergio.

Here there's the code:

```c
void timeDiff() {
    struct tm ts;
    char buf[80];
    long rawtime = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                struct tm end;
                end.tm_mday = region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k].dateHealing.day;
                end.tm_mon = region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k].dateHealing.month;
                end.tm_year = region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k].dateHealing.year;

                struct tm start;
                start.tm_mday = region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k].dateDiagnosis.day;
                start.tm_mon = region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k].dateDiagnosis.month;
                start.tm_year = region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k].dateDiagnosis.year;

                rawtime = difftime(mktime(&end), mktime(&start)) ;

                ts = *localtime(&rawtime);
            }
        }
    }
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%j", &ts);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

Comment: Also: `ts = *localtime(&rawtime);` -  Is the `*` intended?

Comment: Make sure you have the month and year correct, look up how they are stored in `struct tm`. Also you should be using `time_t` for the value passed to `localtime`, and `difftime` returns a `double`. Please take notice of compiler warnings, and read up on the functions and structures you are using. Don't guess.

Comment: @RobertS it is.

Comment: @WeatherVane Why? I only can find the use without `*`, f.e. `struct tm * timeinfo; time_t rawtime; time (&rawtime); timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);`

Comment: we did many tries so far, we're students not senior developer, the main problem is that it works on xcode, run from a macbook, but it doesn't on windows. I've no warning, without `*` doesn't work `difftime` wants long.

Comment: @RobertS because [localtime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) returns a pointer, not a `struct`.

Comment: @Sergio so you are saying your own `.month` is `0` based, and your own `.year` is `1900` based?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, but why to assign that pointer to an object of the struct `tm` instead of a pointer to an object of the struct `tm`? Note that `ts` is not a pointer, it is an object of the struct `tm` itself.

Comment: You are not assigning a pointer to a `struct`, but copying what the returned pointer points to a `struct`. Also, how does it make any sense passing a time *difference* to `localtime`?

Comment: @WeatherVane That´s what I meant. Maybe a little bad explained before.

Comment: You copy a `struct` contents with `=` (but you can't compare it with `==`). So `ts = *localtime(&rawtime);` works just like when the type is, say `int`.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  when passed to the compiler, 5 ERROR messages are output.  Starting with: `STATESICK stateSick;`   because the type: `STATESICK` is not defined anywhere in the posted code.  Also, it is missing the `#include` statements needed for the needed header files, like: `time.h`  You state that it runs, so Please correct the posted code.

Comment: regarding: `{"PlutoPluto","Leonardi","GRSBDT06B48F839T",stayHome,{0,0,0,28,2,2020},{0,0,0,29,2,2020}},`  What are you expecting this to do?  perhaps you meant: `SICKREGION mySickRegion = {"PlutoPluto","Leonardi","GRSBDT06B48F839T",stayHome,{0,0,0,28,2,2020},{0,0,0,29,2,2020}},

Comment: regarding: `{"PlutoPluto","Leonardi","GRSBDT06B48F839T",stayHome,{0,0,0,28,2,2020},{0,0,0,29,2,2020}},`  The comma at the end is an error.  Also, the initialization of the `struct_tm`  instances are missing a value for the `tm_wday` field

Comment: The posted code is missing a `main()` function!  please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: this array: `region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k]` is not defined anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: it can't compile, I know it's just part of the code, just to make you an idea about the function

Comment: you do not initalize struct tm correctly, e.g. tm_year is years since 1900

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your variables

```
struct tm start = {0};
```

`tm_mday`, `tm_mon`, and `tm_year` are not the only fields in a struct tm.